# AngularJS $location not changing the path

Tags: angularjs

I'm having an issue with changing the URL of the page after a form has been submitted.

Here's the flow of my app:

1. Routes are set, URL is recognized to some form page.
2. Page loads, controller sets variables, directives are fired.
3. A special form directive is fired which performs a special form submission using AJAX.
4. After the AJAX is performed (Angular doesn't take care of the AJAX) then a callback is fired and the directive calls the `$scope.onAfterSubmit` function which sets the location.

The problem is that after setting the location the nothing happens. I've tried setting the location param to `/` as well... Nope. I've also tried not submitting the form. Nothing works.

I've tested to see if the code reaches the `onAfterSubmit` function (which it does).

My only thought is that somehow the scope of the function is changed (since its called from a directive), but then again how can it call `onAfterSubmit` if the scope changed?

Here's my code

```
var Ctrl = function($scope, $location, $http) {
  $http.get('/resources/' + $params.id + '/edit.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.resource = data;
  });

  $scope.onAfterSubmit = function() {
    $location.path('/').replace();
  };
}
Ctrl.$inject = ['$scope','$location','$http'];
```

Can someone help me out please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular $location.path not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359553/angular-location-path-not-working)

Comment: Keep in mind that this was created a year before that one.

Comment: Right and with the benefit of an extra year, the other one has a more precisely correct accepted answer.

Comment: @JimG. this is not a duplicate, this question is 4 years ago, the one you link, is 2 years ago.

Answer (score 303, accepted):

I had a similar problem some days ago. In my case the problem was that I changed things with a 3rd party library (jQuery to be precise) and in this case even though calling functions and setting variable works Angular doesn't always recognize that there are changes thus it never digests.

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events, setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries).

Try to use `$scope.$apply()` right after you have changed the location and called `replace()` to let Angular know that things have changed.

Comment: To get a better idea of how $apply works with angular and how to work around it's issues, here's a link for that http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/10/more-angularjs-magic-to-supercharge-your-webapp.html#apply-digest-and-phase

Comment: I've used this approach with the jQM angular connecter, it works great, but I'm using `$location.search()` in a factory when creating the app, and I've got no `$scope` to use apply on. What would I do in that case?

Comment: @Skeater You can simply inject the root scope and operate on it like so: factory('xyz', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {...}])

Comment: Thanks Flex, I've worked that out now... seems obvious in the end. I should have thought about it for longer but it's so easy to just look on Stack Overflow

Comment: Here's some more info about a working $location change.
http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/10/more-angularjs-magic-to-supercharge-your-webapp.html#apply-digest-and-phase

Comment: You can also use `$scope = angular.element(document).scope();` if you're unable to get a `$scope` variable injected.

Comment: @Flek can you provide a code example to help make this answer more usefl? Obviously a lot of people are finding it to be correct and helfpul, but I am not seeing the situation.

Comment: can wrap your callback with $timeout and the scope will be properly applied

Comment: Like JasonS said, use $timeout(function() { //apply changes here }); This has two advantages: 1) You don't need access to $scope. 2) You don't have to worry about $apply alredy running. For The 2nd reason, using $timeout is often the preferred approach.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Just wanted to provide another example of how to do this: [$location.path after a certain timeout does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22148845/1667461)

Comment: `apply()` fixed it on the iPad, but broke it on the Desktop with:
`Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress`.
`timeout()` worked for both.
It feels wrong, but at least it works for now :P

Comment: Wow, I just bumped into this with Angular 1.5. After a call to a 3rd party canvas-to-gif library, the `$location.path()` failed to work in my callback. Following it with `$scope.$apply()` did the trick. Thanks mate.

Comment: Using `$scope.$applyAsync( function() { // changes here })` also works perfectly for me, and avoids potential conflict with digests/apply already in progress.

Answer (score 55):

Instead of `$location.path(...)` to change or refresh the page, I used the service [`$window`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window). In Angular this service is used as interface to the `window` object, and the `window` object contains a property [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location) which enables you to handle operations related to the location or URL stuff.

For example, with `window.location` you can assign a new page, like this:

```
$window.location.assign('/');
```

Or refresh it, like this:

```
$window.location.reload();
```

It worked for me. It's a little bit different from you expect but works for the given goal.

Comment: me too, $location.path() does not redirect when url has params

Comment: This is the correct answer. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33449178/839639)

Answer (score 29):

I had this same problem, but my call to $location was ALREADY within a digest. Calling $apply() just gave a $digest already in process error.

This trick worked (and be sure to inject `$location` into your controller):

```
$timeout(function(){ 
   $location...
},1);
```

Though no idea why this was necessary...

Comment: Nooo this is a bad idea. Just check for phase incase it's within a digest and then you can skip the apply. Angular will catch up with it and change the URL on its own: https://coderwall.com/p/ngisma

Comment: Matsco - That makes sense, but I tried that and $$phase already === '$digest', so angular thought it was within a digest, but it never caught up and updated the location.  (And note - this had worked in an earlier iteration of my code, so I wonder if there is an angular bug where it isn't catching the change and running another digest in certain instances). I think the $timeout is saying, 'hey - even though I'm in a digest, run another when this ones over even if I don't think its necessary'). Regardless, this worked and $apply (with checking for $$phase) did not.

Comment: timeout seems like a dirty hack to me. If your href contains "#", the $location.path() doesnt work as expected. Just remove entirely href="#" on your a tag or just set to href="" and you wouldnt need to use $timeout

Comment: $$phase is a private variable that you should not attempt to access because it might change in a new angularjs version.

Comment: Using $timeout might be a hack, but using $$phase is an even bigger hack. Generally, do not view or touch anything prefixed with $$.

Comment: After about 10 hours of random things breaking... this solution worked for me!

Comment: @sarul Thanks a bunch, that was what was tripping up my noError state...requires the hash in the HTML call, doesn't work with it in the $location call...go figure. -C§

Answer (score 6):

I had to embed my `$location.path()` statement like this because my digest was still running:

```
       function routeMe(data) {                
            var waitForRender = function () {
                if ($http.pendingRequests.length > 0) {
                    $timeout(waitForRender);
                } else {
                    $location.path(data);
                }
            };
            $timeout(waitForRender);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the function, very useful!

Comment: for me the problem was we were using angular-block-ui and it was preventing the update of the address bar location. we decorated the $http request with a bool that our requestFilter picked up so that block-ui didn't trigger on that particular call, and then everything was fine.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem was the optional parameter indicator('?') missing in my template configuration.

For example:

```
.when('/abc/:id?', {
    templateUrl: 'views/abc.html',
    controller: 'abcControl'
})


$location.path('/abc');
```

Without the interrogation character the route obviously would not change suppressing the route parameter.

Comment: It's not *template configuration* but route configuration.

Answer (score 1):

If any of you is using the Angular-ui / ui-router, use:`$state.go('yourstate')` instead of `$location`. It did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

This wroks for me(in CoffeeScript)

```
 $location.path '/url/path'
 $scope.$apply() if (!$scope.$$phase)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion many of the answers here seem a little bit hacky (e.g. $apply() or $timeout), since messing around with $apply() can lead to unwanted errors.

Usually, when the $location doesn't work it means that something was not implemented the angular way.

In this particular question, the problem seems to be in the non-angular AJAX part. I had a similiar problem, where the redirection using $location should take place after a promise resolved. I would like to illustrate the problem on this example.

The old code:

```
taskService.createTask(data).then(function(code){
            $location.path("task/" + code);
        }, function(error){});
```

Note: taskService.createTask returns a promise.

$q - the angular way to use promises:

```
let dataPromises = [taskService.createTask(data)];
        $q.all(dataPromises).then(function(response) {
                let code = response[0];
                $location.path("task/" + code);
            }, 
            function(error){});
```

Using $q to resolve the promise solved the redirection problem.

More on the $q service: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Answer (score -8):

```
setTimeout(function() { $location.path("/abc"); },0);
```

it should solve your problem.

Comment: Running a non-setTimeout is a very bad idea. And, as @matsko said above, $timeout is not the best idea.