# $location not working in AngularJS using d3.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

This is the first time I face the issue and can't figure out why.
I'm using d3 to create an [icicle chart](http://msug.vn.ua/content/d3js/examples/partition/partition-icicle.html).
There is a click event that is firing and calling `changePath()`. I see the console log which means that I do have access to `$location.path` but when I try to set it nothing happens: not a new page, not an error page, nothing!

If I don't change paths via angular my router won't maintain scope which is what I'm looking for.
Any clues?

```
var parentCtrl = function($scope,$location){

$scope.makeBSC = function(){

        var changePath = function(el){
          console.log($location.path());
          $location.path(el)
        }
        var width = 405,
            height = 420,
            color = d3.scale.category20c();

        var vis = d3.select("#bscChart").append("svg")
            .attr("width", height)
            .attr("height", width);

        var partition = d3.layout.partition()
            .size([width, height])
            .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

        var json = data;


        vis.data([json]).selectAll("rect")
          .data(partition.nodes)
            .enter().append("rect")
              .attr("y", function(d) { return d.x; })
              .attr("x", function(d) { return d.y; })
              .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dx; })
              .attr("width", function(d) { return d.dy; })
              .attr("class",function(d){
                if(d.isSel) return "rectBlue"
                return "rectGray"
              }).on("click", function(d){
                changePath(d.goTo);
         });
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I think you'll find the answer to your question in this question: [AngularJS $location not changing the path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784656/angularjs-location-not-changing-the-path)

Comment: Ah! thank you so much! I had tried apply but my syntax was incorrect. Much appreciated! You want to add this as a response so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OCD will not let me leave this question 'open'. So, as groner pointed out... Hi, I think you'll find the answer to your question in this question: [AngularJS $location not changing the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784656/angularjs-location-not-changing-the-path)

Also, a little value-ad. Checkout these directives that wrap d3 http://www.fullscale.co/dangle/