# In Angular, how to redirect with $location.path as $http.post success callback

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, angularjs

I am attempting to make a simple authentication service by sending a Post to a php file, I need it to load the home page partial on my `ng-view` when its successful.

This is what I tried :

```
function loginCtrl($scope, $http, $location){
    $http.post(url,data).success(function(data){
        $location.path('/home');
    });
}
```

Results in my url changing but `ng-view` not updating. It updates when I manually refresh the page.

(routes have been configured properly at the `$routeProvider`, I have tested redirecting this with a standalone function not as a callback and it works )

I have also tried defining `$location.path('/home')` as a function and then calling it on the callback it still doesn't work.

I did some research and found some articles stating this happens when using another third party plugin, I am only loading angular.js

Any insights or pointers to some study material will be great

Comment: what do you mean by ng-view? also, does $location.path() internally call window.location = ...?

Comment: I forgot to mention this is within the context of using angularjs framework. - edited the above

Comment: Interesting! Do you use firebug or something like that? Does your app make a request for a partial, when a route is changed?

Comment: Try calling  $rootScope.$apply() after the $location.path('/home').

Comment: @user1248256 yes it does `.when('/home', {templateUrl:'partials/home.html',controller: myCtrl})`. i am using chrome's developer tools, and it doesnt show a request to home.html.

Comment: @GeorgeAnandaEman, let's try to make unsuccessful request and then change location on error callback. something like that: ```$http.post('\itdoesnotexist',data).error(function($location.path('/home');});``` the partial would be downloaded?

Comment: @GeorgeAnandaEman, btw, did you see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784656/angularjs-location-not-changing-the-path? i bet "yes", but just in case.

Comment: @user1248256 will look it up and try your test asap

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Here is the changeLocation example from this article http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/10/more-angularjs-magic-to-supercharge-your-webapp.html#apply-digest-and-phase

```
//be sure to inject $scope and $location
var changeLocation = function(url, forceReload) {
  $scope = $scope || angular.element(document).scope();
  if(forceReload || $scope.$$phase) {
    window.location = url;
  }
  else {
    //only use this if you want to replace the history stack
    //$location.path(url).replace();

    //this this if you want to change the URL and add it to the history stack
    $location.path(url);
    $scope.$apply();
  }
};
```

Comment: You should probably use the $window service instead of directly using the window object to avoid issues when testing. http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.$window

Comment: A single out-of-function answer: Use $window.location = url;

Comment: i have also written a seperate back history stack

Comment: app.directive("backButton",  function ($window) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind("click", function () {
                $window.history.back();
            });
        }
    };
});

Answer (score 14):

There is simple answer in the official guide:

> What does it not do?
>
> It does not cause a full page reload when the browser URL is changed.
>   To reload the page after changing the URL, use the lower-level API,
>   $window.location.href.

Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Answer (score 3):

I am doing the below for page redirection(from login to home page). I have to pass the user object also to the home page. so, i am using windows localstorage.

```
    $http({
        url:'/login/user',
        method : 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
        data: userData
    }).success(function(loginDetails){
        $scope.updLoginDetails = loginDetails;
        if($scope.updLoginDetails.successful == true)
            {
                loginDetails.custId = $scope.updLoginDetails.customerDetails.cust_ID;
                loginDetails.userName = $scope.updLoginDetails.customerDetails.cust_NM;
                window.localStorage.setItem("loginDetails", JSON.stringify(loginDetails));
                $window.location='/login/homepage';
            }
        else
        alert('No access available.');

    }).error(function(err,status){
        alert('No access available.');      
    });
```

And it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `success`, I change it to `then` and it works.

here is the code:

```
lgrg.controller('login', function($scope, $window, $http) {
    $scope.loginUser = {};

    $scope.submitForm = function() {
        $scope.errorInfo = null

        $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : '/login',
            headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            data: $scope.loginUser
        }).then(function(data) {
            if (!data.status) {
                $scope.errorInfo = data.info
            } else {
                //page jump
                $window.location.href = '/admin';
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use : $window.location.href = '/Home.html';

Answer (score 0):

it's very easy code .. but hard to fined..

```
detailsApp.controller("SchoolCtrl", function ($scope, $location) { 
      $scope.addSchool = function () {

        location.href='/ManageSchool/TeacherProfile?ID=' + $scope.TeacherID;
      }
});
```