# AngularJS would not switch view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, view

I am trying to switch the view, once the "Add" button is clicked (see code below). However, when I click on button "Add", the only thing that happens is that the **"/addRecordType"** is attached to the end of my URL in the browser, instead of resolving it to **'templates/add-record-type.html'** as config instructs  it to do. Why is this happening and how could I make it work? Thanks!

parserconfig.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='parserconfigApp'>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <title>Parser Config</title>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-controller='ParserConfigController as parserConfig'>
    <button ng-click="changeView('addRecordType')">Add</button>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="parserconfigApp.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

parserconfigApp.js

```
var app = angular.module('parserconfigApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.controller('ParserConfigController', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location){        
    $scope.changeView = function(view) {
        $location.path(view);
    }
}]);


app.controller('AddRecordTypeController', ['$scope', function($scope){
}]);


app.config('$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/recordTypeList', {
                templateUrl: '/parserconfig.html',
                controller: 'ParserConfigController'
            }).
            when('/addRecordType', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/add-record-type.html',
                controller: 'AddRecordTypeController'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/recordTypeList'
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
when('/addRecordType', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/add-record-type.html',
    controller: 'AddRecordTypeController'
}).
```

Should be

```
when('/addRecordType', {
    templateUrl: '/templates/add-record-type.html', // Slash added
    controller: 'AddRecordTypeController'
}).
```

Answer (score 0):

Use location.url instead

```
        this.changeView = function(viewName){
            $location.url('/' + viewName);
        }
```

Or you could use ui-router which is an enhanced angular router, popular alternative to angular-route

http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-ui-router.html

Comment: That did not fix the issue. I wonder if you have you tried it?

Comment: I've seen this work with other examples, can't try anything now, on mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my other answer was less helpful, I think this may be your solution.

```
$location.path(view);
```

Is only going to change your URL, without actually loading the new route. If you immediately use

```
$scope.$apply()
```

You should then move to that route.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14387747) for more info