# $location.path is not working

Tags: angularjs

When user has enter correct username and password I want redirect to another location. But when I used `$location.path('dashboard')` here then URL of browser is changed but that page not loaded.when refresh I page using ctrl+R or click on refresh icon of browser then appropriate page is loaded.

```
$http.post('/login', $scope.userInfo)
        .success(function (data) {
            //Check if the authentication was a success or a failure
            //Successful POST here does not indicate success of authentication
            if (data.status === "authentication success") {

                //Proceed to load the dashboard for the user                    
                $location.path('/dashboard');

            } else if (data.status === "authentication error") {
                //Inform user of the error
                $scope.errorMessage = data.error;
                $scope.showErrorMessage = true;
            }

        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.errorMessage = "Error while attempting to authenticate. Check  log.";
            $scope.showErrorMessage = true;

        });
    };

}]);
```

Comment: Have you tried using $scope.$apply after that? 

eg. `if(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()`

Comment: @RafalPastuszak your answer worked for me. Pls put it up as a separate answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular $location.path not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359553/angular-location-path-not-working)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Have you tried using $scope.$apply after that? eg.:**

```
if(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()
```

**This short method comes in handy quite often as well:**

https://github.com/yearofmoo/AngularJS-Scope.SafeApply

Comment: @ShankarKamble why accept the answer if it didn't help you?

Comment: Please don't blindly use `$scope.$apply` without understanding why. It is rarely necessary or useful, since Angular will automatically perform your async callbacks within a digest for you. Needing apply generally means that you've stepped outside the Angular framework unnecessarily, such as by using `jQuery.ajax` instead of `$http`, `setTimeout` instead of `$timeout`, `onclick` instead of `ng-click`, or some other async callback from outside Angular that an Angular wrapper already exists for.

Comment: @MarkAmery yea. I found myself here because of setTimeout. Just didn't know $timeout existed.

Comment: @MarkAmery Very useful comment

Answer (score 14):

To quote https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

> "The $location service allows you to change only the URL; it does not allow you to reload the page. When you need to change the URL and reload the page or navigate to a different page, please use a lower level API, $window.location.href."

So, for example, instead of using:  `$location.path("/path/to/something");`

Use this:  `$window.location.href = "/path/to/something";`

`$window.location.href` will change the URL **AND** load the new page.

Hope that helps.

Comment: In my case I coudn't get this to work with $window so I used just 'window.location.href'.

Comment: Yes, I think it's just `window.location.href`. Using window.location.href was the right solution -- thanks so much.

Comment: To use `$window`, be sure to include it in your function parameters, like so:  `myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($window, $location){...})`

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have 
      **$scope** (like in case of service)
then you can use

```
 $location.path('/path');
 if (!$rootScope.$$phase) $rootScope.$apply();
```

Comment: Nothing else worked for me, but this did. Thanks! :-]

Comment: That's great. Worked perfectly for me in my error scenario. (running a 3rd party handler function from an external library inside my controller and needed to force scope).

Answer (score 4):

Try this (don't forget to inject $timeout):

```
$timeout(function () {
   $location.path('/dashboard'); 
}, 0);
```

Comment: This did it for me. No need for $scope.$apply() with this method

Answer (score 0):

Use $timeout(function){} this will work

Comment: Thanks for the advice

Answer (score -2):

Use `$rootScope.$evalAsync`

*for example:*

```
$rootScope.$evalAsync(function() {
     $location.path('/dashboard'); 
});
```

Answer (score -6):

Try:

```
 $location.path('/dashboard');
 $location.reload();
```

Comment: .reload() is not a valid method on the $location object