# Angular $location.path not working

Tags: angularjs

I have a question similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784656/angularjs-location-not-changing-the-path), but different.

Here I am trying to add an event listener for a [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) handler.

```
app.run(function ($location, $window, $rootScope) {
  $window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
      $location.path("/abc");
      console.log($location.path()); // this prints "/abc" as expected

      $rootScope.$apply(); // this has no effect

      $scope = angular.element(document).scope(); // this is the same as $rootScope
      $scope.$apply(); // so this also has no effect
  });
});
```

The `$location.path` isn't being recognised by Angular.

The other question says that I should call `$apply()` on the scope, but the only scope available to me is `$rootScope` and calling `$apply()` on that doesn't seem to work.

A comment on the answer suggests that a scope can be got with

```
$scope = angular.element(document).scope()
```

but this gives me the `$rootScope`, which doesn't work.

How do I get angular to regocnise the change in `$location.path()`? Is there a better way to register a `message` callback in such a way as I can change the path?

Comment: and you see that event fires properly?

Comment: If you mean does the event listener fire then yes, I have a debugger breakpoint.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You should run the expression as function in the `$apply()` method like

```
app.run(function ($location, $window, $rootScope) {
  $window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
      $rootScope.$apply(function() {
        $location.path("/abc");
        console.log($location.path());
      });
  });
});
```

See [documentation - ng.$rootScope.Scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope).

If you want to improve testability, use `$console` instead of `console` and inject that object as well.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks very much. (I was only using the log for the purpose of illustrating this question).

Comment: This does not work for me, as I get a digest already in progress error. I don't understand why the $apply should be necessary to begin with, angular should be aware of the path change since you are using the $location service to instigate it.

Comment: Update: Calling $location.replace() on the line after I call $location.path() fixed it for me. No need for $apply().

Comment: Although the OP is using `$rootScope`, I think that `$scope` should suffice.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted solution is not the appropriate way to do it. Ideally you shouldn't need to interfere with the digest cycle (which $apply() does).

The best way according to me is calling $location.path() from the MainController. Use `$emit - $on` to send it to the MainController and have a function call $location.path from there.
It will redirect you flawlessly without having to interfere with the digest cycle.
I hope this helps someone.

Comment: I'm in the main controller, trying to use location, but it's not working. I tried the accepted solution, sometimes it works, sometimes it does not, angular complains about the digest cycle when this happens. Can I emit an event to somewhere and catch it? Remember I'm in the main controller. And, if possible, how to catch it?

Comment: @MateusPires use $timeout it will not trigger a digest when one is taking place, but when it all finishes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, my mistake was that I was running the ng-click directive badly on my item.

Bad example:

```
<a **href="#"** ng-click="myFunctionChangeLocationPath()">...
```

Example well:

```
<a ng-click="myFunctionChangeLocationPath()">...
```

And so you can correct the problem!

Comment: This doesn't address the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is solution without $timeout.

Just prevent redirect to default state before using $state.go

```
event.preventDefault();
$state.go('root');
```