# AngularJs: $location.path not working correctly

Tags: angularjs

I am having a weird issue with location.path(),as I don't get redirected to the page I want.
I have a link in my HTML file as follow:

```
<a title="{{woa.name}}" href="#/" ng-right-click="" href="javascript:void(0)"  ng-click="goToDetailPage(woa.pk,'workofart')">
```

The corresponding controller has the following code:

```
appTreasure.controller("mySecondController", function($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.goToDetailPage = function(pk, selectedDetailsPage) {
        newLocation = selectedDetailsPage + '/' + pk;
        console.log("NEW: " + newLocation);
        $location.path(newLocation);
    }
    // some more unrelated code
```

The current URL is: `<base>/#/beinspiredby` and the printed newLocation is something like `<base>/#/workofart/someexistingpk`. So, I am building the new location with valid values.

Unfortunately, when I click on the link, I get redirected to `<base>/#/`. 
If I manually go to `<base>/#/workofart/someexistingpk` I correctly land to the page I am looking for.

Furthermore, in a third controller, I have exactly the same code for `goToDetailPage` and it works.

Where am I missing something?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359553/angular-location-path-not-working

Comment: I am not working outside Angular nor am I adding an event listener. Why should it be a duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is it because you have an href attribute in your anchor element (actually you have two).

Try this

```
<a title="{{woa.name}}" ng-right-click="" ng-click="goToDetailPage(woa.pk,'workofart')">
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually it is enough to drop href="#/", which was an old thing.