# AngularJS $location not working in logout function

Tags: angularjs

Already read this topic [Angular not changing the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784656/angularjs-location-not-changing-the-path) and [Angular location path not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359553/angular-location-path-not-working) But still not get the idea why this thing happen.

Here is my function in controller.

```
$scope.logout = function () {

sessionService.destroy('isLoggedIn');   
sessionService.destroy('role'); 
sessionService.destroy('sessionToken');

if(sessionService.get('sessionToken') != null){
//$scope.isLoggedIn = true; 
$scope.hasNotsignedIn = false;  
}else {
$scope.hasNotsignedIn = true;   
//$scope.isLoggedIn = false;
}

$location.path("/"); //this not working 

}
```

`$location` already injected to controller and route already define. I have other `$location.path` in other function which is work correctly.

So is something missing or wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

If the path is the same `$location.path("/");` will not work.

You have to use `$route.reload();`

Comment: just trying to `$location.path("/otherPath");` and `$route.reload();`as you said but still not working.