# Pubnub AngularJS hereNow function - Route to a different view?

Tags: angularjs, pubnub

I'm wondering how I can route to a different view when I'm working with this `Pubnub` function here.

> QueueController

```
Pubnub.hereNow(
    {
        includeUUIDs: true,
        includeState: true
    },
    function (status, response){
        console.log(response);
        //do some algorithm with response
        $location.path('/chat');
    }
);
```

So basically I'm getting the `response` from this `hereNow` function and then when the algorithm passes a condition inside, I want it to go from my `QueueController` to my `ChatController` so the users can begin chatting! I even removed the algorithm from the function and had the route just by itself, but it doesn't work at all.

When I put the `$location.path('/chat')` *outside* of my `hereNow` function, it does route very nicely.

So how does one *route* to a different view in this case?

Comment: I think you need to pass $location in the function as parameter and then it will work

Comment: hello Ghulam thanks for your answer!

Comment: My pleasuere :)

Answer (score 2):

Just discovered [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359553/angular-location-path-not-working) and it seems to be working!

```
Pubnub.hereNow(
    {
        includeUUIDs: true,
        includeState: true
    },
    function (status, response){
        console.log(response);
        $rootScope.$apply(function(){
            $location.path('/chat');
        });
    }
);
```

I added the `$rootScope` as a dependency in my `QueueController`

```
app.controller('QueueController', ['$scope', '$location', '$rootScope', 'languageService', 'Pubnub',
    function($scope, $location, $rootScope, languageService, Pubnub){ ... }]);
```