# Angular JS & Phonegap back button event

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I have a MainCtrl containing a backstack for history, like this;

```
$scope.urlHistory = [];

$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
    if ($location.$$absUrl.split('#')[1] !== $scope.urlHistory[$scope.urlHistory.length - 1]) {
        $scope.urlHistory.push($location.$$absUrl.split('#')[1]);
    }
});
```

Then, in the same controller I've got a GoBack() function I'd like to call when the back button is pressed;

```
$scope.goBack = function () {
    $scope.urlHistory.pop();
    $location.path($scope.urlHistory[$scope.urlHistory.length - 1]);
};
```

This is supposed to work because from my index.html I call it with ng-click="goBack()" and everything works as expected.

I use this for the device events, same controller;

```
function onBackKeyDown() {
  alert("back");
  $scope.goBack();
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
  // Register the event listener
  alert("deviceready");
  document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
};
```

I can see the alerts, but the app's not navigating back. Something happens though, because if I press the device back button twice, the ng-click="goBack()" suddenly takes me back to the start page of the app. Am I using $scope wrong? Experiencing this on Win Phone & Android. Using Phonegap Build.

**edit: What I'm really after here is why would my $scope.goBack(); function work differently when called from the devicelistener.**

Comment: What is the overall purpose of this code? Is it just to navigate to the previous page when the user clicks the back button?

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear, that's exactly what the purpose is indeed.

Comment: I know a bit better what is going wrong. $location.path(); does not work when invoked by the event listener. Calling it with ng-click works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved it:

```
  $scope.goBack = function () {
    if (urlHistory == '/') { 
      document.removeEventListener("backbutton", onBackKey, false);

    };    
    urlHistory.pop();
    $location.path(urlHistory[urlHistory.length - 1]);
    $scope.$apply();
  };
```

The scope.$apply(); was my answer. It's necessary when executing angular expressions outside of angular. ([AngularJS $location not changing the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784656/angularjs-location-not-changing-the-path))

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use the browser's built-in history object for this.  For example:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function () {
        window.history.go(-1);
    });
}
```

You shouldn't need to do anything specific just because you're using angular.  Unless I'm missing something else...

**UPDATE:**  After looking at the [phonegap docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton), it looks like the default `backbutton` behavior already does what you want... or are you trying to do something special?

Comment: You're right, except the default back button behaviour for Windows Phone (8) seems to be exiting the app. That's why I'm using my own "history object". Also, window.history.go(-1) does not work on Windows Phone.

Comment: Ok, sorry. Whenever I've done phonegap development I've only ever targeted iOS and Android so I'm not familiar with windows phone quirks. But the principle should be the same. Whatever cross-platform code that will go back in the browser's history should go in the `"backbutton"` listener.  See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588315/how-to-check-if-the-user-can-go-back-in-browser-history-or-not) for more info.