# Angularjs $location.url doesn't work, location.href works

Tags: routes, location, directive

When I try to change the location within my controller it loads server's root, not the certain page:

```
'use strict';

eventsApp.controller('TestController',
    function TestController($scope, $location){
        console.log('test comes here!');
        $scope.makeTest = function(){
            $location.url('/test');
        }
});
```

I have a router like this:

```
'use strict';

var eventsApp = angular.module('eventsApp', ['ngResource','ngSanitize'])
    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
        $routeProvider
          .when('/test',{
            templateUrl:'templates/test.html',
            controller:'TestController'
        }).otherwise({
            templateUrl:'templates/default.html',
            controller:'DefaultController',
            redirectTo:''
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

In my index.html I set the directive

```
<base href="/">
```

It seems that everytime it implements *otherwise*. However if I use

```
location.href = '/test';
```

instead of

```
$location.url('/test');
```

, then it works.
I have no idea about such a behavior. Do you?

Comment: You need to use `$scope.$apply()`
see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784656/angularjs-location-not-changing-the-path

Comment: I tried to do so before. It tells me: Error: $apply already in progress

Answer (score 3):

Though this question relates to state here's how you can navigate to another url:

```
$location.url(myUrl);
```

This should work but I've seen some issues with it - i.e. it will call the code but just not go anywhere. If this is the case you could also use the `$window` service like so:

```
$window.location.assign(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have a `$scope.apply()` already running, consider using `$timeout` as a workaround.

Not perfect, but shall do the job. 
Better case: set a global variable which you set to "loaded" once your api are done loading, then update your function/call scope related actions.

Comment: This fixed my problem of `$location.url(newUrl)` not working inside an `ng-click` handler.