# Angular $location change path works second time, not first time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The code seems simple, but as I read [the docs for $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location), I notice there's a LOT of complexity I don't understand.  My setup is as follows:

```
// in app.js
$routeProvider.when('/done'     , {templateUrl: 'partials/done.html', controller: 'DoneController'});

// in my controller where $location is injected, on a button press...
if (!$scope.errors.length) {
    $scope.model.save().then(function() {
        alert("did I get here?");
        $location.path('/done');
    });
}
```

I press the button and see the alert, but no change in view.  I press the button a second time (saving data to the cloud a second time), I see the alert a second time and the view does change.  Any ideas why?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle showing your issue?

Comment: Is there a 'resolve' in your controller ? Also, what if you wrap the $location.path('/done') in a $scope.$apply ?

Comment: @AlexHv - no resolve, but wrapping in $apply worked.  Any idea why?  Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS $location not changing the path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784656/angularjs-location-not-changing-the-path)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe there must be something asynchronous in your sequence.
It generally happens when using an external libraries like jQuery.

The problem is that the `$watch -> $digest -> $apply` cycle of angular is not triggered with external libraries events. So the change has been made, but not propagated by angularjs.

Using `$scope.$apply()` will solve your problem

```
if (!$scope.errors.length) {
    $scope.model.save().then(function() {
        alert("did I get here?");
        $scope.$apply(function(){
          $location.path('/done');
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I agree that $scope.$apply is the way to go when asynchronous events get generated out of the Angular framework, which I'm sure is the case with his call to $scope.model.save(). But $timeout is part of the Angular framework, you shouldn't be using $scope.$apply within a $timeout callback. That's the point of $timeout I guess.

Comment: Dude you're absolutely right, sorry for this. I correct.

Comment: On the other hand, you could illustrate with setTimeout() which is the most basic call being both async AND out the framework.

Comment: Yeah I mixed up those two I guess ! Thanks for the precision :-)

Comment: Thanks.  My model.save() ultimately calls parse.com, fitting your theory about being outside the framework.  I thought I had parse apis wrapped in angular promises via a project I found on github, but investigating now, I see that code is not running.  Thanks for the tips (thanks also @zrz).

Answer (score -1):

i am not sure why? but this may be your html problem.if your html like this:

```
<a href="#" class="btn" ng-click="myFunction()">submit here</a>
```

then  do `href=""` means code should be like this:

```
<a href="" class="btn" ng-click="myFunction()">submit here</a>
```