# Angularjs $location.path() not redirecting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook

why is it that I am not redirected to other URL when I use angular.js $location.path ?

```
.controller('CheckCtrl', function($scope, $localStorage, $location) {
    $scope.check = function(){

        if($localStorage.hasOwnProperty("accessToken") === true) {
            alert("CheckCtrl logged in" + $localStorage.accessToken);
            $location.path("/post-report");
        }else{
            alert("CheckCtrl not logged in" + $localStorage.accessToken);
            $location.path("home.login");
        }
    };

})
```

Even though `$localStorage.hasOwnProperty` is true already since it contains token from Facebook.

I also try `$location.reload()` but still no luck.

Comment: There are lots of the same questions here, but check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784656/angularjs-location-not-changing-the-path) post out.

Comment: Actually, I already viewed that post and I try to add `$scope.apply` after `$location.path('home.login')` but still it doesn't work. I also `alert()` the path to check, it gives me the correct path.

Comment: it doesn't work for me too.

Comment: Try the solution from @PauloOliveira in this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784656/angularjs-location-not-changing-the-path i think is the last answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this :-

```
$location.path("/post-report").replace();
or 
$location.path("/post-report");
if(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()
```

It replace your current location with the new location.

Comment: It doesn't work either. I'm using Ionic framework for mobile app.