# Unable to update URL params using $location.search()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to apply default params to a URL if they don't exist. Successively, I copy URL params to a local variable (`$scope.params`) and then load content:

```
// If limit and sort params are defined
if ($location.search().hasOwnProperty('limit') && $location.search().hasOwnProperty('sort')) {
    // Update scope params
    $scope.params = $location.search();

    // Load content
    $scope.loadContent();
} else {
    // Merge URL params and scope params; don't override URL params
    $location.search(utilityFactory.mergeObjects($location.search(), $scope.params, false)); // REMEMBER THIS AS #1

    // Replace browser history entry
    $location.replace();
}
```

I have another function that I invoke when changes to `$scope.params` are made to update URL params:

```
$scope.updateParams = function () {
    // Reset pagination
    delete $scope.params.skip;

    // Update URL params
    $location.search($scope.params); // REMEMBER THIS AS #2
};
```

In #1, the controller gets initialized and the control goes into `if(){}` instead of `else{}`. Perfect. However, in #2, the `$location.search()` does not refresh the controller. If I do a force reload after #2 using `$route.reload()`, the controller gets initialized twice.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS $location not changing the path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784656/angularjs-location-not-changing-the-path)