# $locationPath leads to Error: [$rootScope:inprog]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I need to switch view in my angular js webapp.

In order to handle the routing, I am using the $stateProvider, as here:

```
.config(['$httpProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($httpProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('common', {
                templateUrl: 'assets/html/template.html',
                abstract: true,
            })
            .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                parent: 'common',
                templateUrl: 'app/models/authentication/views/login.html',
                controller: 'LoginController'
            })
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                parent: 'common',
                templateUrl: 'app/models/home/views/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeController'
            })
            ...
```

Inside my login controller, I am trying to switch the view (from Login to Home)

```
  .controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$cookieStore', '$location', '$window', '$http',
function ($scope, $rootScope, $cookieStore, $location, $window, $http) {

        $scope.login = function () {

            loadHttp();
        };

        function loadHttp() {
            var url = "http://myurl";
             ...
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.$apply(function () {

                        $location.path('/home');
                        console.log("$location.path: " + $location.path);
                    });
                });
        }
```

But when I reach *$location.path('/home');* I get this error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:3000/adminTool/assets/js/angular.min.js:6:416
    at t (http://localhost:3000/adminTool/assets/js/angular.min.js:126:132)
    at r.$apply (http://localhost:3000/adminTool/assets/js/angular.min.js:133:515)
    at http://localhost:3000/adminTool/app/models/authentication/controllers.js:46:32
    at http://localhost:3000/adminTool/assets/js/angular.min.js:119:129
    at r.$eval (http://localhost:3000/adminTool/assets/js/angular.min.js:133:313)
    at r.$digest (http://localhost:3000/adminTool/assets/js/angular.min.js:130:412)
    at r.$apply (http://localhost:3000/adminTool/assets/js/angular.min.js:134:78)
    at g (http://localhost:3000/adminTool/assets/js/angular.min.js:87:444)
```

What am I doing wrong? How to get rid of it and finally switch view?

I read to use $apply from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784656/angularjs-location-not-changing-the-path)

PS: I am very new to angular

Comment: why you are using `$apply` you want to change the state you can inject `$state` and call `$state.go('home')

Comment: you don't have a `/home` route being shown in the code you posted.  You have a `/` route that is the `home` *state*.  You also haven't shown the `.otherwise()` clause, but at a guess, it probably directs back to the `/login` route, and since you don't have a `/home` route, you are stuck in an endless loop.

Comment: Why don't you use $state.go('home') instead of $apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is because of the `$scope.$apply` around the `$location.path('/home')` statement. Angular is already in a digest loop so triggering it again within that loop (by calling `$apply`) will give you this error. Removing the `$scope.$apply` will therefor probably fix your problem.

The reason the digest loop is already triggered is because you are probably using the `$http` service which uses a promise to return the value. Angular always triggers a digest when resolving this promise.

But aside from that you probaly want to use the `$state` service to move to another state instead of moving to another location using the `$location` service. `$state.go('home')` would probably be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think here is the problem `$location.path('/home');`
You don't have path `/home` you have state called `home`
so you need to go  `$location.path('/');` or inject `$state` and use method `$state.go('home')`, also you do not need to wrap it inside `$apply`